# i need some assistance my text based game

Tags: python

Is there a way to make my code repeat after a "death" in my text based game without a `systemexit.exit()`?

---

I have tried to search loops but nothing, I have looked at other games online, and I have searched this website for anything that can help

---

```
if option==1:
    print('\nyou break the front bericade but as you walk in you see a laser streatching across the door frame a little too late,  you died')
    thisdict["death"] = True
    print('\nyou died')
    SystemExit.exit()
```

---

I want it to just say you died then start you at the beginning and say so, but a system exit doesn't do that very well.

Comment: Usually the way to do this would be to run your game code inside a `while` loop, so when a player dies you can give them the option to restart or exit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop, prepare your games state dictionary and call your game-function.
When you die, return out of it, ask for continue and create a "new" game state dict:

```
def game(starter):
    # do stuff
    lr = input(f"Hello {starter['name']} - nothing to see but go Left or Right? [L,R]: ").lower()
    if lr == "left":
        return  # doing anything is futile, you die anyhow 
    else:
        return # doing anything is futile, you die anyhow 

def main():
        state =  {"name": "someone"} 
        while True:
            game(state)
            if not input("You are dead - Play again? [y,n]").lower() == "y":
                break
            # create new games state dict (just altering the name here)
            state["name"] += "_again"
        print("bye")

main()
```

Output:

```
Hello someone - nothing to see but go Left or Right? [L,R]: l
You are dead - Play again? [y,n] y
Hello someone_again - nothing to see but go Left or Right? [L,R]: r
You are dead - Play again? [y,n] y
Hello someone_again_again - nothing to see but go Left or Right? [L,R]: nothing
You are dead - Play again? [y,n] n

bye
```